# "Rearrange the alphabet" puzzle

Tags: word, cipher

I've been trying to solve this for quite a while, it's been about 1 week.

My friend sent this to me to solve it.

Please do help

Xabj, lbhe yvzvgf, fgbc obgurevat zr, gunax lbh!!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please could you make clearer what the puzzle is here? All we have is the title "rearrange the alphabet" and a string of letters (which isn't 26 letters long and has two Z's, so it can't be the alphabet rearranged).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually a very simple shift (caesar) cipher. Just shift all letters by 13 and you get your solution.
So when A = 1 and Z = 26
Add 13 to the letter and you get your solution:

> Know, your limits, stop bothering me, thank you

Because it is 13 so exactly half of 26 decrypting and encrypting is exactly the same operation

You can try it out here:
http://www.xarg.org/tools/caesar-cipher/

Comment: In other words, ROT-13: the simplest of all Caesar ciphers!

Comment: @Ivo It seems that you just became a 2k user. Congrats.

Comment: @randal'thor: Except ROT26, of course.

Answer (score 4):

It is a substitution cipher which says:

> Know, your limits, stop bothering me, thank you